# android editText onTextChanged called dozens of times even when no text is changed

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am implementing a shopping cart in my application. In my cart view I have a list of products with a editText so the user can change their quantities.
I need to listen to the "quantity change" event so I can update my Cart object accordingly.

I am trying to use onTextChanged event but its not working as expected. Just when I open my cart view the event is fired like dozens of times and breaks completely my product quantity values.

How can I make sure the value is really changed?

Here is my code:

**My CartItemsListAdapter (responsible for rendering each row of the cart).**

```
public class CartItemsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CartItem> implements OnClickListener{

    private ArrayList<CartItem> cartItems;

    /**
     * view holder for caching the view elements
     */
    static class CartItemViewHolder {   
           TextView tvProductName;
           TextView tvShopName;
           TextView tvSubTotal;
           EditText edQuantity;
           Button btnRemoveFromCart;    
           ImageView ivProduct;
    }

    /**
     * default constructor
     * @param context
     * @param textViewResourceId
     * @param cartItems
     */
    public CartItemsListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<CartItem> cartItems) {

        super(context, textViewResourceId, cartItems);
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        CartItemViewHolder viewHolder;
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.cart_item, null);
            viewHolder = new CartItemViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvProductName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_product_name);
            viewHolder.tvShopName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_shop_name);
            viewHolder.tvSubTotal= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_subtotal);
            viewHolder.edQuantity = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_product_quantity);
            //viewHolder.btnRemoveFromCart = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_remove_item);
            viewHolder.ivProduct = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_product_image);

            v.setTag(viewHolder);

        }else{
            viewHolder = (CartItemViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        CartItem item = cartItems.get(position);
        if(item != null){
            viewHolder.tvProductName.setText(item.getProduct().getName());
            viewHolder.edQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(item.getQuantity()));
            viewHolder.tvSubTotal.setText(Double.toString(item.getSubTotal()));
            viewHolder.tvShopName.setText(item.getProduct().getShop().getName());

            UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(viewHolder.ivProduct, item.getProduct().getImage());

            viewHolder.edQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new CartItemQuantityChangeListener(cartItems,item));

        }

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cartItems.size();
    }


    @Override
    public CartItem getItem(int position) {
        return cartItems.get(position);
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**My TextChanged listener class**

```
public class CartItemQuantityChangeListener implements TextWatcher {

    private ArrayList<CartItem> cartItems;
    private CartItem item;

    public CartItemQuantityChangeListener(ArrayList<CartItem> cartItems,
            CartItem item) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
        this.item = item;
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        try {

            int quantity = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "quantity changed" + quantity);

            int index = this.cartItems.indexOf(item);
            Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "INDEX" + index);
            // this.cartItems.get(index).setQuantity(quantity);

            /*
             * for(CartItem i : this.cartItems){
             * Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG,item.getProduct().getName() + " : " +
             * i.getQuantity()); }
             */

        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the last value that was written in the edittext in a String and everytime onTextChanged is called you compare the new value with the old. If the new value is diffrent, then do something. And if its the same value you dont do anything

Answer (score 1):

> you should remove this line from the get view method in your code .

```
    viewHolder.edQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new 
CartItemQuantityChangeListener(cartItems,item));
```

> then it is not
>   adding the multiple textwatcher for the each view.. add the above line
>   in adapter constructor then it will work fine..

Answer (score 0):

I guess that each time you are building a new View, you are adding a new `TextWatcher` to the `TextView`. So at the end, the `afterTextChanged` method is called a number of times equal to the number of items in your list.